How do I catch events in an eventBox with gi-gtk ang GTK3
I would like to port a program written with gtk2hs (Gtk2) to gi-gtk (Gtk3) and I don't understand how to catch click, scroll and other events.
In my previous code I created a event box and catched the button pressed event and then getting which button where pressed by using tryEvent and eventButton, eventClick and eventModifier.
event <- eventBoxNew

event `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do
    bout <- eventButton
    time <- eventTime
    mod <- eventModifier
    clic <- eventClick
    (x,y) <- eventRootCoordinates 
    case (bout,clic,mod) of 
              (RightButton,SingleClick,[]) ->  liftIO $ do ...
              (RightButton,SingleClick,[Control]) ->  liftIO $ do  ...

I found many equivalent function in the gi-gtk api but the function tryEvent don't exist anymore. The functions getEventButton eventGetState eventGetClickCount require an
Event as parameter
eventGetCoords :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m) => Event -> m (Bool, Double, Double)
eventGetClickCount :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m) => Event -> m (Bool, Word32)
onWidgetButtonPressEvent event $ tryEvent $ do
    bout <- getEventButton
    time <- eventTime
    (mb,mod) <- eventGetState
    (cb,clic) <- eventGetClickCount
    (ob,x,y) <- eventGetCoords
    case (bout,(cb,clic),(mb,mod)) of 
              (Gdk.BUTTON_SECONDARY,(True,1),(False,_)) ->  liftIO $ do ...

              (Gdk.BUTTON_SECONDARY,(True,1),[Gdk.ModifierTypeControlMask]) ->  liftIO $ do  ...

What is this Event parameter to give to these function. Where does it come from ?
I found these functions eventGet,newZeroEvent which seems to create an Event.
How should I use them ?
Do you have an example of code (in any language) for catching events in an EventBox with Gtk3 or Gtk4 ?

You get your hands on an Event using the event signal:
eventBox <- new EventBox []
on eventBox #event \ev -> do
    ... -- in this block, ev :: Event

But I think a lot of the button stuff isn't in there, possibly because there's a different signal for that one.
on eventBox #buttonPressEvent \bev -> do
    ... -- in this block, bev :: EventButton

I haven't found the docs for EventButton. It doesn't appear to be in any of gi-atk, gi-gdk, gi-gio, gi-glib, gi-gobject, gi-gsk, haskell-gi, or haskell-gi-base. Dunno what's up with that.
